# failed to call system call with gcc inline assembler (64-bit)

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm trying to call the system call `write` with the inline assembler (gcc 4.2.1, Mac OS 10.7.5) the code compiles successfully but there isn't any output at all. This is the complete code:

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "Test\n";
    // write(1, s, 5);
    asm(
        "movq $1, %%rax;"
        "movq $1, %%rdi;"
        "movq %0, %%rsi;"
        "movq $5, %%rdx;"
        "syscall;"
        :
        : "r"(s)
        : "%rax", "%rdi", "%rsi", "%rdx"
    );
}
```

Compile with gcc:

```
$ gcc main.c -o test
```

Run:

```
$ ./test
```

By running the code with the Xcode 4.5 debugger I get this error:

```
Thread 1: EXC_SYSCALL (code=1, subcode=0x1)
```

What's wrong with the code? It runs successfully with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks!

Comment: System calls don't necessarily have the same numbers on Linux & Mac OS X.  You can find lots of information with a simple trip to Google.  Here's a link that describes translating a simple program from Linux to Mac OS X: http://thexploit.com/secdev/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the system call number is different.  You need to put `0x2000004` in `%rax` to get this program to work on Mac OS X.

I'm not really sure how your program works on Ubuntu, either, since you're using the `exit` syscall number `1` in your example, rather than `4` for `write`.

Comment: The numbers in 32-bit and 64-bit Linux aren't the same. Have a look over here: http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/linux_syscalls_64bit.html